# How to update apps on old iPad without App Store

Tags: ios, software-update

Im using an old IPad that I just got and I’m trying to play a game but whenever I open the game it asks me to update it, brings me to the App Store just to tell me there’s no update. What do I do?

Comment: Did you sign into the App Store and download those games yourself or did they come with the iPad?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible the new update is not available for your old iPad, requiring a new version of iOS.

- Make sure your iPadOS is up to date in Settings → General → Software Update.
- Search the App Store for the app and check the compatibility section at the bottom of the app listing to make sure the latest version is still compatible with your iPad.